# Firebase neither onDataChange or onCancelled are being called

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have users in the database like this :

[image: users database]

I try to read the user using a helper class 
and there is this method

```
public void readUser (final FirebaseUserHelper.DataStatusUser dataStatus)
{
    mReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            user = (User) dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

            dataStatus.DataIsLoaded(user,userKey);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("User", databaseError.getMessage() );

        }
    });
```

When I debug, I see that the reference is good but the `onDataChange` or `onCancelled` methods are **not** being called.

```
public class FirebaseUserHelper {
    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mReference;
    private String userKey;
    private  User user;
    public interface DataStatusUser
    {
        void DataIsLoaded( User user, String key);

    }

    public FirebaseUserHelper()
    {
        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        userKey = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        mReference=mDatabase.getReference("Users").child(userKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: If neither `onDataChange` nor `onCancelled` is being called, that usually means the device doesn't have an internet connection, or no connection to the Firebase Database backend.

Comment: Strange because in other activities I do  update and read fine

Comment: Where are you calling `readUser()`?

Comment: in my login activity, i check if the user is connected to app 
  if(autoUser!=null ) {
..
 readUser()
}

My goal is to check if the user is of a certain type so that I move it to the appropriate activity.

l also call readUser in another activity and this work fine